# Punishment for damage from an Ayin Hara according to the Zohar and Kabbalah

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, reward-punishment, ayin-hara-evil-eye

Ive read that when it comes to din / punishments, one may only be punished for physical actions (including speech / lashon hara) but never because of thoughts and emotions.

However, what about the concept of ayin hara? in the zohar its descibed how sara / hagar was a subject to ayin hara, in so that an "evil" thought can create an happening. is there really no punishment for this?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! I suggest that you [edit your profile](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) and give yourself a name. Could you please [edit] into this post as much as you can about where you've seen the concept in your first paragraph?

Comment: You also have the cases in the Gemara where Rabbis would look at people and turn them to bones (end of Berachos, 2nd chapter of Shabbos regarding a few people)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is addressed in Rabbi J David Bleich's article in *Tradition*, ["Liability for Harm Caused by Metaphysical Forces"](http://traditionarchive.org/news/article.cfm?id=105751)

The Talmud in Bava Kama has plenty of cases where our courts can't punish someone, but Heaven will demand punishment (e.g. various cases of psychological damage); there's also talk about if you render your friend's wine or cow non-kosher: it still looks like perfectly-fine wine or or a perfectly-fine wine, but metaphysically it's no longer the same.

Presumably you're asking about the punishment for employing metaphysical means to physically damage someone. If I recall correctly, Rabbi Bleich says it depends how those metaphysical means work -- are you *asking* God to cause the damage (but He may say no), or is it no different than shooting someone with a physical gun, just with different mechanics (where if God allows things to follow their normal course, damage would occur). He cites both interpretations; in the former interpretation, one would certainly be exempt, at least from the justice our courts can render.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer, I will look into the article and the Bava Kama. About your question, yes, I was thinking more along the lines of the last option - if you want to harm by thinking negative about a person, lets say for example due to jealousy and envy.